# can we display other html page information in same page

Tags: html

I am building webpage with several pages.i don't want to use links to go to those pages. i have given the page numbers in the bottom of the page. but when i click that page number the page should information of other page should in the same page.how can i achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm afraid we will not be able to help you since your question lacks detail. What did you try so far, what was the result? Please also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to redirect to another page you have to use a frame (the easier way, but really uglier) or AJAX. The AJAX code is easy, if you need it I'll post by comment :)

Comment: I'll write you in a new answer, here you would see it bad

Answer (score 0):

Chris Coyier at CSS-tricks has a [great article](http://css-tricks.com/dynamic-page-replacing-content/) explaining a non-frame SEO friendly technique for doing just that.

Answer (score 0):

```
var oXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();

oXHR.open("get", "page.php?num=1", true); // here you get the page you need

oXHR.onreadystatechange = function ()
{
   if (oXHR.status != 200)
   document.getElementById('page_displayed').innerHTML = "Error: " + oXHR.status + " " + oXHR.statusText;
   else
      document.getElementById('page_displayed').innerHTML = oXHR.responseText;
      // here will be displayed your content
}

oXHR.send(null);
```

This is the AJAX code. Then in "page.php" you would have to write something like (I'll write in pseudo-code):

```
<?php
   // ipotize you see 10 post for every page
   $post = 10;

   $page_num = $_GET['num'];

   // select from database the content you need
   $sql = "SELECT content FROM pages LIMIT 0, ".$post;
   // OR (if you have more html contents for different pages)
   // if ($page_num == 1)
      {
 ?>
 <html code here>
 <?php
      }

      // in each case you must return some text, it will be displayed on your page
 ?>
```

Ask if you don't understand :)

Answer (score -1):

Yes frames is going to be the best thing for you.

Is the link for details http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_frames.asp

Comment: Frames are great, but only if you target Netscape Navigator.

Comment: Most browser still support frames.  You could use ajax but that's not SEO friendly although i dont know frames are aswel.  The easiest solution is frames.  Its not want I do but its what he as asked for.

Comment: @david allen not completely true. See google webmaster central to read on AJAX and SEO. It is possible, but I think at the moment this is above the horizon of the person who asked this question.

Comment: I agree.  Did know that google is now looking at Ajax content.